# WebDriver (Java) - Exclude elements under a Table when using driver.findElements()

Tags: java, xpath, webdriver

Using WebDriver, I am writing a code to find all elements of a specific kind on a given area of a page (which can also be the entire page itself).

Let's say my page is like this

```
<div id='mydiv'>
    <a href='#' id='mylink_1'>Link 01</a>
    <a href='#' id='mylink_2'>Link 02</a>
    <span>Enter your name</span>
    <input type='text' id='txtName' value=''/>
    <div id='mytable'>
        <table id='mytableelement'>
            <tr>
                <td><a href='#' id='table_link_1'>Table Link 1</a></td>
                <td><input type='text' id='table_text_1' value=''/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href='#' id='table_link_2'>Table Link 2</a></td>
                <td><input type='text' id='table_text_2' value=''/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href='#' id='table_link_3'>Table Link 3</a></td>
                <td><input type='text' id='table_text_3' value=''/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, my requirement is to, say, get all the links under the div 'mydiv'.

So, I've written a code like this

```
WebElement myDiv = driver.findElement(By.id("mydiv"));
List<WebElement> links = myDiv.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
```

This will return me **All** links under 'mydiv', which is fine. However, I want to exclude the links that occur under the **table** tag, that is, links with ID 'table_link_1', 'table_link_2','table_link_3'.

In order to achieve this, I did the following

```
ArrayList<WebElement> finalLinks =  new ArrayList<WebElement>();
WebElement myDiv = driver.findElement(By.id("mydiv"));
List<WebElement> links = myDiv.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
for(WebElelemnt link:links){
  try{
      WebElement containingtable = link.findElement(By.xpath("ancestor::table[1]"));
      System.out.println("Element occurs inside a table. So, skip it");
  }
  catch(Exception e){
      finalLinks.add(link);
  }
}
```

This seems to work too, but the only problem is, if the table contains 1000 rows, then it loops for 1000 links, only to skip them. This obviously hits performance.

IS there a faster way of skipping the links under the table?

**Note:** The table here is only an example. I may want to skip a specific div or a set of divs which are nested too.

Can there be a generic way of doing this?

Thank you,
Sriram

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know, is to use an xpath expression.

Try

```
WebElement myDiv = driver.findElement(By.id("mydiv"));
List<WebElement> links = myDiv.findElements(By.xpath("./a"));
```

this should return only then links you want (direct child of div).

For example the xpath expression "./tbody/tr" will only match table rows of the "current" table, rows of nested tables will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if selenium supports the `:not()` pseudo selector. 
You may want to try something like this:

```
List<WebElement> anchors = driver.findElements(
    By.css("#myDiv :not(.skip1) a, #myDiv > a")
);
```

Instead of using `:not(.skip1)` you can also use something like `:not(table)`.
I am not that familiar with the `:not()` yet. It maybe that the selector above matches something like

```
<div id="myDiv>
   <div class="skip1">
       <div class="evilDivMaybeBypassingTheNotPart"><a href="...">...</a></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

accidently.

Here's a fiddle to play around with: http://jsfiddle.net/fabian_barney/ad4vuaf9/ 
Another fiddle with your HTML code: http://jsfiddle.net/fabian_barney/n5Lcg9ar/2/

Comment: Hi @Fabian Barney, the JSFiddle link doesn't work. Can you please post the correct link? Thank you.

Comment: Seems that it got deleted. I'll make a new one - give me some minutes.

Comment: Fiddle should be fine now.